# change text color or highlight text with multiple colors using python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, colors, highlight

I am trying to read the pdf and highlight some sub-strings in pdf, and i am able to achieve it using python libraries **PYPDF2** and **fitz**

but i wanted to make to highlight/ change text with different colors and retain the layout of the original pdf,

please advice on this, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can't change the textcolor of words inside the pdf but we can use the

> highlight annot

with default color("yellow"),

if need more colors we need to make the

> square annot

using **pymupdf** lib, this worked for me in python